# Does the Apache webserver provide an API for programmatic live configuration changes?

Tags: web-server, configuration, apache-2.4

I'm using Apache as an authenticating web cache in front of Tomcat.

Periodically, we will take a dynamic resource and save a copy to the webserver. Rewrite rules on the webserver route requests through to the static copy.

If possible, I'd like to be able to modify these rules on the fly. I'd also like to be able to initially set the rules from Tomcat, to avoid the need for double configuration.

Is there an API for Apache for making such changes? It could be directly via Apache or, if there's a third-party app that provides this, that would work too.

(Unfortunately "api", "apache" and "configuration" are way too common a set of search terms to get useful results)

Comment: I haven't used it, but you could check out [webmin](http://webmin.com/) per the related Stackoverflow question [Looking for apache web server configuration API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734527/looking-for-apache-web-server-configuration-api). Based on my quick look, it doesn't seem like that answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't; the most live you can get is modification of an `htaccess` file.

Instead, maybe have some custom code running within Apache that can achieve the same end while being configgable via API?